# MySQL 8. Tables created too slowly

Tags: mysql, innodb, ubuntu-22.04

Empty server. Ubuntu 22.04 
Empty database. MySQL 8.0.33.
InnoDB tables 
Why each table creation lasts from 0.6 to 1 sec.
There are only 3-4 columns. Without data.

```
mysql> show profile for query 1;
+-------------------------------+----------+
| Status                        | Duration |
+-------------------------------+----------+
| starting                      | 0.000181 |
| Executing hook on transaction | 0.000181 |
| starting                      | 0.000030 |
| checking permissions          | 0.000013 |
| creating table                | 0.733726 |
| After create                  | 0.000674 |
| waiting for handler commit    | 0.000025 |
| waiting for handler commit    | 0.088327 |
| query end                     | 0.000022 |
| closing tables                | 0.000008 |
| waiting for handler commit    | 0.000035 |
| freeing items                 | 0.000037 |
| cleaning up                   | 0.000047 |
+----------------------+----------+
14 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What type of storage are you using?

Comment: SSD, if I understand your question right

Comment: There have been numerous reports of slow performance in MySQL 8.0 when making changes in the data dictionary. Here's an example: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106390

Comment: Why does it need to be fast? Normally this is nothing you do very often

Comment: Lots of FKs?  Indexes?  Constraints?

Comment: No. 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
  `id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `limit` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`log_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: @Thallius One scenario where you would need CREATE TABLE to be fast is if you run setup and teardown steps during automated integration tests.

Comment: If the problems occur on an NVMe, this bug report might help:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93734

Comment: @IvanV  This  - CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl ( id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, type tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, limit int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY type (log_type) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; -  is illogical.  The is no column named log_type - so it will never be successful.  Please give us examples that are legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

On my local development machine (AMD Ryzen 5 5600 / NVMe / 64GB RAM) with MySQL8.0.34 a

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Inno1 ( myfield CHAR(20)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

takes between 1.5sec(!) for the first time and 0.7sec for each additional CREATE. My normal scripts were twice as slow as on my 6 year old machine with SSD.

There are bug reports related to NVMe hardware issues, specifically Samsung 970 Pro and their clones:
[MySQL Bugreport](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93734)

All attempts to solve the problem via MySQL parameters were largely ineffective or made the situation even worse.

The only thing that helped was the nobarrier way via a separate MySQL partition:
[MySQL write performance on I/O-barrier](https://davidalger.com/posts/mysql-write-performance-and-io-barriers/)

Since then the first CREATE takes 0.01sec, following 0.00sec and my import scripts run 3x faster than on the old machine.

For this purpose, a separate partition is created and used as datadir for MySQL.

The .my.cnf then contains, for example:

```
[mysqld]
datadir = /mnt/database/mysql
```

In the /etc/fstab then:

```
UUID=the-mysql-partion-id /mnt/database/   ext4   rw,relatime,nobarrier   0   2
```

That's all. However, this solution is probably not recommended for production server.

Maybe helpfull: [How-To Move MySQL Data Dir on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-20-04)